# Selecting random class from weighted class probability distribution

Tags: python, random, numpy

I have a solution that I've scratched out, but it's a tad messy:

First, let's say we have a random number from a uniform distribution we'll be using to select a random class from a class probability distribution:

```
r = 0.525325235325
```

And a list of classes, along with a corresponding list of values representing a class probability distribution for the four classes:

```
classes = ["w", "x", "y", "z"]

distribution = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

Now, to get the cumulative probabilities:

```
b = [sum(distribution[0:x + 1]) for x in range(len(distribution))]
>>> b
[0.1, 0.30000000000000004, 0.6000000000000001, 1.0]
```

So far so good. Now, select a class by the weighted probability:

```
c = [y for y in b if y > r][0]
>>> c
0.6000000000000001
```

And to get the selected class:

```
selected = classes[b.index(c)]
>>> selected
'y'
```

Putting it all together:

```
r = 0.525325235325
classes = ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
distribution = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

b = [sum(distribution[0:x + 1]) for x in range(len(distribution))]
selected = classes[b.index([y for y in b if y > r][0])]
```

This works well enough. The thing is, it will be called each time the class probability distribution is updated along with a complex code base – so efficiency matters.

Are there any ways I can make this code more efficient in terms of speed and/or memory usage (eliminating b without the expense of additional processing would be nice) in Python? Alternatively, is there an established algorithm for this problem that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Using dictionaries is faster than lists. Your distributions can serve as keys to find the corresponding values instead of using indexed lists.

Comment: That's a fair point, I'll look into it. The code base may make that tricky off the cuff, but nothing a little refactoring can't fix. Thanks : )